# Close modal on click outside, but [hidden] is tied to @Input, don't know when ready

Tags: angular

I have a component for viewDetails. Its input is a name. I display the details modal if name != null. On close I set the name = null. Pretty straight forward... except I'm having trouble making it close when I click outside of the modal.

I have the directive setup and it works great; however, how can I tell it when it should be "actively" listening or not.

Right now I'm just using name as a real name or as null to manage show/hide functionality.

Parent Component:

```
<button (click)="detailName = item.name">Details</button>
<my-detail [(name)]="detailName"></my-detail>
```

Detail View:

```
<div [hidden]="!name">    // full screen with gray background
  <div (clickOutside)="close()">   // inner modal contents
```

Detail Controller

```
  @Input() name: string;
  @Output() nameChange: EventEmitter<string>;

  close() {
    this.name = null;
    this.nameChange.emit(null);
  }
```

The (clickOutside) directive works as intended, if you click outside of the modal the close function is called. However, the issue is that on the button click the elements are generated, but the clickOutside event fires since it's outside of the modal. I also cannot use some kind of clickOutsideIsActive boolean based on name != null, since at that time name has just been set.

I understand why it's not working, but want to know how I can change to get the desired behavior. I know I can wrap everything in emitters on onCreate stuff but I really like how clean and simple this is setup. Appreciate your feedback.

**Update** okay looks like I got it, or least have a path to a solution. Using lifecycle hook OnChanges, watching for it to change, and throw the isActive in a timeout or something.  ... Okay, solved, answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using angular2 lifecycle hook onChanges you can keep an isActive flag and pass that to the closeOnClick directive. Example...

```
<div [hidden]="!name">
  <div (clickOutside)="close()" [clickOutsideActive]="isActive">

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    let change = changes['name'];
    if(!change) return;  // if no property name, don't do anything

    // if setting name to null (close), deactivate click watching
    else if(typeof change.previousValue === 'string' && !change.currentValue) {
      this.isActive = false;
    }
    // if setting name to string from null (open), activate click watching
    else if(typeof change.currentValue === 'string' && !change.previousValue) {
      // timeout used to let modal open before it tries to close itself
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isActive = true;
      });
    }
  }
```